# Write pure text using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, text

Is there a way to write text (and not decode special characters) using Javascript?  I have tried `document.write()` but it appears to convert characters like `&amp;` back to `&`, while JQuery's `.text()` keeps `&amp;`.

**My code**

```
<script>document.write('&amp;');</script>
```

**What it returns**

```
&
```

**What I want it to return**

```
&amp;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just convert all the `&` to `&amp;` and it should work for you:

```
stringToBeWritten = "Hi&Hi - Hi&amp;Hi";
stringToBeWritten = stringToBeWritten.replace(/(&)/gi, "&amp;");
document.write(stringToBeWritten);
```

```html
<script>
  stringToBeWritten = "Hi&Hi - Hi&amp;Hi";
  stringToBeWritten = stringToBeWritten.replace(/(&)/gi, "&amp;");
  document.write(stringToBeWritten);
</script>
```

*ps: Don't use* `document.write()` *as it is not good. See [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)*

**Solution 2**

We can actually use the browser itself to make this happen.

```js
function escapeStuff (unescaped) {
  DiV = document.createElement("div");
  DiV.innerText = unescaped;
  return DiV.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="un" value="& <>" /> <input onclick="res.innerText = escapeStuff (un.value);" value="Escape it!" type="button" />
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: thank you, this did work and i will accept it in 15 minutes when it allows me.  Also what should I use instead of `document.write()`?

Comment: Use `theID.innerHTML` or `theID.innerText` or `theID.textContent`.

Comment: How does document.write's implementation differ in each browser?

Comment: Have a look at: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write).

Comment: Writing to a document that has already loaded without calling document.open() will automatically perform a document.open call. Once you have finished writing, it is recommended to call document.close(), to tell the browser to finish loading the page. The text you write is parsed into the document's structure model. In the example above, the h1 element becomes a node in the document.

Comment: @Juhana Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: Can you point to a specific answer in that question about different browsers? I don't see any at a first glance.

Comment: @ccjmne, I see that now, I guess I would have to do many `.replace()` functions unless someone else finds a way.

Comment: @Jaketr00 You don't need to do many... That's one. `/g` will make it global.

Comment: @PraveenKumar but to then replace other characters like `<`, `>`, `"`, `'`.

Comment: @Jaketr00 Or if you need a quickie, as I said you before, this will take care of everything. `element.innerText = escaped; escaped = element.innerHTML;` - Do you understand this? `:)`

Comment: @Jaketr00 ^ That works for what you asked. `:)` Should I update in the answer?

Comment: @PraveenKumar yeah you should.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96481/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-jaketr00).

Comment: @Juhana Who downvoted my answer? Is there anything I can do to make it better?

Comment: How should I know who downvoted? I'm just waiting for a reference to the claim that document.write's behavior is browser-dependent.

Comment: @Juhana I just gave it to you and also updated it in the answer man! Have a look!

Comment: @Juhana No man, just worried. Sorry if I am bothering you. Really sorry.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33985583/write-pure-text-using-javascript/33985599#comment55726813_33985599) still stands – I don't see how your link has any relevance.

Comment: Read this @Juhana: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice**

Comment: I have read it **and none of its answers say that implementation differs in each browser**. Yes, there are many reasons why document.write should be avoided, but browser compatibility is not one of them.

Comment: @Juhana *Updated the answer*.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, simply use `element.textContent` instead of `document.write` :)

For example, check [this JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/e7sfu1xv/3/) or the code snippet below:

```js
document.getElementById('myspan').textContent= 'Click &lt;HERE&gt;';
document.write('Click &lt;HERE&gt;');
```

```html
With element.textContent: <span id="myspan"></span>
<br />
With document.write():
```

---

***Update:*** replaced usage of `innerText` by `textContent` as suggested by Leon Adler in the comments.

Comment: This still appears to display the `<` instead of `&lt;`.

Comment: No, only with `document.write()`, that I left here for comparison, but **not** with `element.innerText` :)

Comment: `innerText` is **non-standard** (Internet Explorer) property and was not supported in Firefox before version 45. Using *textContent* would be advised.

Comment: Oh thank you, I didn't even know that actually! Updating my answer right away :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between *html* and *text*. You want to set **text**:

```
var myText = 'A &amp; B';

// Setting HTML: Result text will be "A & B"
document.write(myText);   // <- don't use document.write!
jQuery('#myElement').html(myText);
myElement.innerHTML = myText;

// Setting Text: Result text will be "A &amp; B"
document.write('A &amp; B'.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;'));   // <- don't use document.write!
jQuery('#myElement').text(myText);   // removes all children and sets the text of the element
myElement.textContent = myText;   // sets the text of the element
myElement.innerText = myText;   // removes all children and sets the text of the element
```

Note that `document.write` is *usually a bad idea*, since it only works when your page was not loaded completely, and using `document.write` later (like when clicking a button) will *replace the entire content of your page*.

I can also advise against using `innerText`. It is a **non-standard** property which was defined by Internet Explorer and later adapted by Chrome, but is not supported in Firefox (which is fine, seeing as it is not in the standards). You can use `textContent` instead.